# React js this.setState is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I am learning React and building a tic-tac-toe game. 
My code is below:

```
var Square = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { mark: this.props.mark,
                clicks: 0
             };
        },

        respondToClick: function() {    
            if(this.state.mark == '_') {    
                var nextClick = this.state.clicks + 1;

            }   
            var newMark = nextClick%2 ? 'X' : 'O';                  
                this.setState({mark: newMark, clicks: nextClick});              
        },  
        render: function(){
                return (<button className="square" onClick={this.respondToClick}>
                {this.state.mark}
                </button>
                );
        }
    });

    var Board = React.createClass({

         renderSquare: function(i) {
                return (<Square mark='_' />);
        },
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { 
                clicks: 0
             };
        },
        changeValue: function(i, val) {
                return (<Square value={val} />);
        },
        render: function() {
                const status = 'Next player: X';
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="status">{status}</div>
                        <div className="board-row">
                            {this.renderSquare(0)}
                            {this.renderSquare(1)}
                            {this.renderSquare(2)}
                        </div>
                        <div className="board-row">
                            {this.renderSquare(3)}
                            {this.renderSquare(4)}
                            {this.renderSquare(5)}
                        </div>
                        <div className="board-row">
                            {this.renderSquare(6)}
                            {this.renderSquare(7)}
                            {this.renderSquare(8)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        }

    });

    var Game = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="game">
                        <div className="game-board">
                            <Board />
                        </div>
                        <div className="game-info">
                            <div>{/* status */}</div>
                            <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
        }
    })

    ReactDOM.render(
            <Game />,
            document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

In my `Square` component I have `respondToClick` method and inside the method I have:

```
this.setState({mark: newMark, clicks: nextClick});
```

Well, somehow neither mark nor clicks get updated. I could use a callback but in my case I do not see how I can do that... Can anyone please help?

Comment: as an unrelated side note, it is recommended to use the ES6 syntax for react nowadays. I would check out [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are storing your state on whose turn it is too low in the hierarchy.

Right now you have it such that when you click on an empty square it will increment the click count to 1 and then set the mark of that square to X. This will never change because in this function

```
respondToClick: function() {    
    if(this.state.mark == '_') {    
        var nextClick = this.state.clicks + 1;
        var newMark = nextClick%2 ? 'X' : 'O';                  
        this.setState({mark: newMark, clicks: nextClick});                                  
    }               
},
```

you only update state once when the square is '_' and never again. If you remove that if statement you will see your count correctly increments and the mark correctly changes.

However, the solution to your overall problem of not having the turn change so when you click a square it turns to X and when you click another it turn to O can be solved by just moving the state of whose turn it is up to the Board component's state.

Comment: actually removing the if statement did not make it better - now every time I click the empty button I get an X, and only if I click the same button repeatedly, I get an O. So it register click count per button not per board.How can I move the state to the Board component?

Comment: Right, so basically you need to keep track of whose turn it is in your board state and then on each move change whose turn it is. The first design to come to my head is adding a turn key in the Board's state and have it be 0 or 1 and then every time you click a square, invert it. To keep track of which squares are what you could have a simple array that matches to each spot in the board's state that you update and send down to each component as a prop. I would recommend playing around with it as that is the best way to learn!

Comment: Thanks. How would I set Board's state from Square?